# How to fetch value of dropdown in function using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple dropdowns in my form which are being created dynamically. I want to fetch the value of selected dropdown option inside function.

```
  <select class="form-control" id="sel1" name="dropdwn">
    <option value="'.$r['2'].'">'.$r['2'].'</option>
    <option value="'.$r['3'].'">'.$r['3'].'</option>
    <option value="'.$r['4'].'">'.$r['4'].'</option>
    <option value="'.$r['5'].'">'.$r['5'].'</option>
    <option value="'.$r['6'].'">'.$r['6'].'</option>
    <option value="'.$r['7'].'">'.$r['7'].'</option>
    <option value="'.$r['8'].'">'.$r['8'].'</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('select[name="dropdown"]').each(function(){
 console.log($(this).val())
});
```

Will return selected value on of each dropdown.

You should include the above js inside your `$(document).ready(function(){}})` function.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the value of the select

> $('#sel1').val()

now if they are dynamic and you are putting that "1" after "sel".. then you can loop on all the select and get the values too

like

```
$( "select" ).each(function( index ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).val() );
  console.log(this.id);
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by whole query ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a common class for all dropdowns.

Say,

```
<select name="select1" class="dropdown">
<select name="select2" class="dropdown">
<select name="select3" class="dropdown">
<select name="select4" class="dropdown">
```

And the JS will be:

```
$('.dropdown').on('change', function(){
var selectedVal = $(this).val(); // this will return selected dropdown value
alert(selectedVal);
});
```

Comment: bro its not working even alert is nt working plz help me ........ My whole code is inside while loop

Comment: Can you provide a sample piece of your code. So that I can understand how your dropdowns are created.

Comment: did you include jquery js link in your html?

Comment: yes. If you are using jquery in your html. You should. Moreover, I just provide him a sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Since the are dynamically created you may need to delegate the event

```
$(document).on("change",'select[name="dropdown"]', function(){
 alert($(this).val())
});
```